# "In its entirety" vs "in entirety"

Tags: expressions

Where should "in its entirety" be used in place of "in entirety"?

Consider the following paragraphs. Which usage is correct, and is the alternative incorrect / less correct, or simply not as common?

"We received a lot of information. Therefore, we elected to relay it in entirety."

"We received a lot of information. Therefore, we elected to relay it in its entirety."

Comment: Both are perfectly acceptable in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/entirety?q=entirety) only lists *"in its entirety"*, as does [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/entirety?q=entirety) (I checked for both US and UK English).

Moreover, *"in its entirety"* is significantly more common: in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, *"in entirety"* appears 11 times, compared to the 576 times that *"in its entirety"* appears.

One possible reason for this is that *"in entirety"* could result (in many pronunciations) in the same syllable being repeated: /**ɪn ɪn**ˈtʌɪərəti/, while the longer version breaks up the two identical syllables: /**ɪn ɪts ɪn**ˈtʌɪərəti/, making it easier to pronounce perhaps, or even just making it sound better.

Answer (score 0):

both are generally acceptable based on the premise.
but the first line is comparatively extra pertinent than the other.

a "lot of information" is described here it its whole. that's generally perceived as a large number, more often than not, but not as a rule.
         information, regardless of how quantitatively rich, can be perceived as (pertinently) qualitative, if you get my drift. ie., even a lttle can be valuable

therefore the former "in entirety" is more descriptive than "in its entirety."

the latter can be thought to describe a single unit of information. in your example, the set of information is generally a very laden value (if something is considered for "relay" rather just "transfer" I'd say it's quantitative as well as qualitative.) But since it could also be limited/small in quantity, the second line can't be incorrect if used.

(this is a personal intellectual analysis and doesn't site nothing.. duh, obviously?)

I'd use the first line in a blink. make no mistake, in this case, both sentences are not unlike correct. effort perseverance courage venom